# Select rows with the same Item name and show lowest Price Value

Tags: mysql

We have a two tables laid out as:

```
Products
ID | Item | Supplier
1 | Harry Potter | Warner
2 | Harry Potter | Warner
3 | Game of Thrones | HBO
4 | The Simpsons | Warner
5 | The Simpsons | Warner
```

AND

```
Prices
ID | Price
1 | 10.99
2 | 20.00
3 | 20.00
4 | 10.00
5 | 12.00
```

I'm trying to get the ID of the lowest priced Item where there are two items with the same name and supplier.

I can get the rows where there are duplicates as:

```
SELECT
Products.ID,Products.Item,Products.Supplier,Prices.price
FROM
Products
LEFT JOIN Prices ON Prices.ID = Products.ID
WHERE Products.ID IN (
SELECT ID FROM Products WHERE Supplier="Warner" GROUP BY Item HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

How can I then modify this to show only the Products.ID of the lowest priced duplicate Item name ?

I have tried ORDER BY but this throws an error for me.

The result should be:

```
ID | Item | Supplier | Price
1 | Harry Potter | Warner | 10.99
4 | The Simpsons | Warner | 10.00
```

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: what is the error in order by clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` in subquery then `GROUP BY` in main query

```
SELECT n.ID, n.Item, n.Supplier, n.Price
FROM 
  (SELECT p.ID, p.Item, p.Supplier, pr.Price
   Products p INNER JOIN Prices pr 
   ON p.ID = pr.ID
   ORDER BY price ASC) AS n
GROUP BY Item, Supplier
```

**Sample Output**

```
ID   | Item            | Supplier | Price
1    | Harry Potter    | Warner   | 10.99
4    | The Simpsons    | Warner   | 10.00
3    | Game of Thrones | HBO      | 20.00
```

To get result where there are two items with the same name and supplier

```
SELECT n.ID, n.Item, n.Supplier, n.Price
FROM 
  (SELECT p.ID, p.Item, p.Supplier, pr.Price
   Products p INNER JOIN Prices pr 
   ON p.ID = pr.ID
   ORDER BY price ASC) AS n
GROUP BY Item, Supplier
HAVING COUNT(n.ID) > 1
```

**Sample Output**

```
ID   | Item            | Supplier | Price
1    | Harry Potter    | Warner   | 10.99
4    | The Simpsons    | Warner   | 10.00
```

Comment: @Rick: Was this any helpful ?

Comment: Perfect works great and v.quick. Thanks for the full explaination